# Extend Angular $q resolve function to accept two parameters instead of one

Tags: angularjs, q

I want to extend *then* function in $q to make the resolve callback accept 2 parameters instead of one, so I can do:

```
myPromise.then(
  function success(data, extra) {
    //do something
  },
  function error() {
    //do something 
  }
);
```

Looking around I found a module that defines a new function called *spread*, that does something similar to what I need, but if the first argument of the success function is an array, it will "spread" each element as a new argument of the function, which is not what I want, first argument should remain as an array, and also I will like to extend *then* instead of creating a new one. I wanted to start by modifying that script but to be honest I'm not even sure how it actually spreads the arguments:

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('$q-spread', [])
        .config(['$provide', function ($provide) {

            $provide.decorator('$q', ['$delegate', function ($delegate) {

                var originalDefer = $delegate.defer;

                $delegate.defer = function () {
                    // Get the prototype of the promise
                    var promiseProto = originalDefer().promise.constructor.prototype;

                    // Add the spread method
                    Object.defineProperty(promiseProto, 'spread', {
                        value: function (resolve, reject) {
                            function spread (data) {
                                return resolve.apply(void 0, data);
                            }

                            return this.then(spread, reject);
                        },
                        writable: true,
                        enumerable: false
                    });

                    return originalDefer();
                };

                return $delegate;
            }]);
        }]);
})(window.angular);
```

So, how do I extend then to accept 2 arguments in the success/resolve function?

Comment: Why don't you just resolve the promise with an object `$q.when({ data: data, extra: extra})` ... That way you don't have to change core code, you won't lock yourself into this particular implementation of `$q` and you can add a more data anytime you want.

Comment: @NicholasRobinson I can't unfortunately. This is also a bit of academic curiosity, to be honest

Comment: This will require to patch *all* $q API in `decorator` and will efficiently make $q noncompliant with Promise/A spec. How should it behave if `$q.resolve(resolvedPromise, rejectedPromise)` is called? It will be not a promise but something else, basically. It is not that easy to seamlessly use $q with async/await, but then it will be impossible. In modern JS promise spreads are handled with destructuring, there's no need for separate `spread` method.